# Wagtail - Using different templates with the same page model

Tags: django, bokeh, wagtail

I am building a website with Wagtail/Django.

Most of my pages consist of some text followed by a graph or table generated with Bokeh.

The way I found to add the Bokeh  and  codes to each page is by using custom template tags. I have created a function that outputs the Bokeh code and I call this function using a template tag.

Therefore a typical template in this site looks like:

```
{% load customtemplatetag %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container py-4">    
    <h1>
    {{ page.header|richtext }}
    </h1>
    <p class="lead">
    {{ page.plead|richtext }}    
    </p>
    {% bokehgraph as bokehg %}
    {{ bokehg.1| safe }}    
    {{ bokehg.0| safe }}  
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Therefore, I have a page model with a dedicated template for each different type of Bokeh Output.

It does not feels like the best way of doing it.

Is there any way I can use the same model with different templates, or maybe a totally different approach that will enable me to use less page models and less templates?

**Edit:**
Following up on the comment from Richard Allen:

I have different template tags that return different graphs. My customtemplatetag file looks like:

```
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def bokehgraph():
    
    Loads data from database1
    Generates graph with Bokeh      

    return components(layout)

@register.simple_tag
def bokehgraph2():

    Loads data from database2
    Generates another graph with Bokeh      

    return components(layout)
```

The .1 and .2 attributes are the `<div>` and `<script>` generate by Bokeh components.

What I need is to be able to select from Wagtail CMS if bokehgraph or bokegraph2 is going to be called for a given page.

The solution that I have now is to have two models, with two templates. One template calls bokegraph and the other calls bokehgraph2.

Comment: Probably need more info on that template tag. Where does it pull the data from for example? And what are the .1 and .2 attributes returned? As is, I can't see why this would need separate templates or models ... The template tag should just return the relevant HTML for rendering no?

Comment: Thanks @RichardAllen, I have updated the question with the answers to your questions.

Comment: More questions ;) What determines if it's db1 or db2 data that's used? Is it some property of the page? Or one that could be added to the page? Are the two graphs generated with the same code or there a difference? Could this be refactored to use same code with parameters?

Comment: @RichardAllen. The graphs are totally different, they show different data from different databases. The pages have the same structure, but they show different texts and different graphs. The codes from both tags are totally different as well. I could refactor it to have one tag that generate both codes, but I need a way to choose from CMS which graph will be used. One option would be to have one model, one template, both tags included in the template as default, and then turn the tag on/off from the CMS depending on the type of page that I am creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the two graph types have very different inputs so can't use the same parameter options.

Rather than two page models, it might be a better route to create a StreamField with one block type per graph type (2 for now, but you can add more this way). If you only ever want one graph per page, then you can set the min/max block values. Since you can specify a front-end template for the block, this logic is taken out of the page template.

So if the two graphs are called Type A and Type B, you might do something like:

```
class TypeAGraphBlock(StructBlock):
    ... block attributes ...
    
    class Meta:
        template = 'blocks/graph_type_a_block.html'
        label = _("Type A Graph")
        icon = 'some icon'

class TypeBGraphBlock(StructBlock):
    ... block attributes ...
    
    class Meta:
        template = 'blocks/graph_type_b_block.html'
        label = _("Type B Graph")
        icon = 'some other icon'

class YourPage(Page):
    ... page attributes ...

    graph = StreamField(
        [
            ("type_a_graph", TypeAGraphBlock()),
            ("type_b_graph", TypeBGraphBlock()),
        ],
        verbose_name="Graph",
        min_num=1, 
        max_num=1,
        use_json_field=True
    )

    ... rest of page definition ...
```